# sql Plugin not working in Production Server and it could not find the jdbc drivers

Tags: jdbc, xpages-extlib

I have created a plugin for connecting to sql thru jdbc driver in my development server. I tried to install the plugin thru update site , but i doesnt work for me for some reason.then copied the plugin into the  "domino\workspace\applications\eclipse\plugins" folder in my server. and the connection is successfull. Then i copied the same plugin in my production server, but the connection fails, it throws error saying "it could not find the driver". what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Extension library version is different in Development and production server. Later i upgraded my production server with latest version of extension library and the problem is solved.